# Taking a photo and copy it to an SD card automattically

Tags: camera, photo, avr

Is there a way to write a code in bascom avr language to take a photo in JPG format and copy it to an SD card automatically? the camera model is Tcm8230md.

Answer (score 0):

I never used the BASCOM [sd-card library](http://www.mcselec.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=291&Itemid=57%22sd-card%20library%22) but there is one. The [I2C library](http://avrhelp.mcselec.com/index.html?using_the_i2c_protocol.htm%22I2C%20library%22) is quiet easy to handle. So the communication should be possible.
But it also depends on how fast you want to shot the photos. I used once a SD-card but with a C-library and I wasn't able to achieve high r/w rates.
Additionally the camera doesn't support jpeg output. But it has an RGB output so you could generate a [bitmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format%22bmp%22).

So I think it might be possible.